# Compile cryptopp using Visual C++ 2010 Express

Tags: compilation, crypto++

I need to compile cryptopp (32-bit) using Visual C++ 2010 express. I downloaded the 5.6.1 version, opened the crypttest.sln, VS required to do some conversion - which failed. The *.vcproj files have x64 platform specified in them which - somehow - fails. I tried to tweak the .vcproj files and remove the x64, but it staill fails on some strange error:

```
This application has been updated to include settings related to the User Account Control 
(UAC) feature of Windows Vista. By default, when run on Windows Vista with UAC enabled, this 
application is marked to run with the same privileges as the process that launched it.     This
 marking also disables the application from running with virtualization. You can change
UAC related settings from the Property Pages of the project
```

I need to compile the static library in some different mode (need to link it to a different dll), but I somehow cannot find out how to even load it into the Visual Studio.

Comment: That's the "error" I pasted above (about the UAC feature). If it doesn't look like an error to you, neither it does to me, but it fails and it reports this as the reason.

Answer (score 0):

That problem has been around for a while. See, for example, [How to use solutions and projects between Visual Studio 2005 and 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/djpark/archive/2007/11/07/how-to-use-solutions-and-projects-between-visual-studio-2005-and-2008.aspx) from the MSDN blogs.

You can change it from the Project's property page. See [/MANIFESTUAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384691.aspx) on MSDN.

[image: UAC Property Page]

You can also open the `*.proj` file (or `*.projx` file) and remove it by hand. Just look for the offending line number; or search for `EnableUAC` (and friends) under the `Link` node in the XML. There might be four different entries - one each for `Debug` and `Release`, and one each for `x86` and `x64`.

[image: UAC PROJX file Link Node]